# SQL Performance Issue : Timing Out

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-performance, query-tuning

Following SQL query is taking more than 5:19 minutes to execute in Production. This SQL is dynamically generated from server side C# code and takes long time to execute for few clients. Due to long time in production Web service is timing out. Can you please optimize this SQL to improve performance ?

Here is the dynamically generated query -

```
SELECT *
  INTO #TepmBase
FROM PFInputDemoV3.dbo.Position_Level_Data_Audit
WHERE PFA_Unique_Identifier = 'TEST_DRILLDOWN_ADVISER'
AND Business_Date BETWEEN '4/1/2017' AND '6/30/2017';

CREATE INDEX IX_TepmBase_ID ON #TepmBase (ID);
CREATE INDEX IX_TepmBase_Audit_Date ON #TepmBase (Audit_Date);

SELECT DISTINCT ID
  INTO #TempBaseDeleted
FROM #TepmBase
WHERE Audit_Date < '8/30/2017 2:09:22 PM'
AND Action LIKE 'Dele%';


SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNumber
  INTO #TepmBaseExtend
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY Audit_id DESC) AS Rank
  FROM #TepmBase t
  WHERE Audit_Date < '8/30/2017 2:09:22 PM'
    AND NOT Action LIKE 'Dele%'
    AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM #TempBaseDeleted)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM #TepmBase
      WHERE Audit_Date BETWEEN '8/30/2017 2:09:22 PM' AND '8/30/2017 2:10:46 PM')) c
WHERE RANK = 1
  AND (ValidatedStatus = 1 OR ValidatedStatus = 3 OR ValidatedStatus = 5
       OR ValidatedStatus = 7 OR ValidatedStatus = 9 OR ValidatedStatus = 11
       OR ValidatedStatus = 13 OR ValidatedStatus = 15 OR ValidatedStatus = 17
       OR ValidatedStatus = 19 OR ValidatedStatus = 21 OR ValidatedStatus = 23
       OR ValidatedStatus = 25 OR ValidatedStatus = 27 OR ValidatedStatus = 29
       OR ValidatedStatus = 31 OR ValidatedStatus = 33 OR ValidatedStatus = 35
       OR ValidatedStatus = 37 OR ValidatedStatus = 39  OR ValidatedStatus = 41
       OR ValidatedStatus = 43 OR ValidatedStatus = 45  OR ValidatedStatus = 47
       OR ValidatedStatus = 49 OR ValidatedStatus = 51  OR ValidatedStatus = 53
       OR ValidatedStatus = 55 OR ValidatedStatus = 57  OR ValidatedStatus = 59
       OR ValidatedStatus = 61 OR ValidatedStatus = 63);



CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_#TepmBaseExtend_RowNumber ON #TepmBaseExtend (RowNumber);

SELECT
  ID,
  PFA_Unique_Identifier,
  Fund_Unique_Identifier,
  Business_Date,
  Information_Date,
  Position_Unique_Identifier,
  Instrument_Group,
  Instrument_Category,
  Instrument_Type,
  Option_Instrument,
  Price,
  Local_Price,
  Quantity,
  LongShort,
  Market_Value,
  Notional_Value,
  Issuer_Counterparty,
  Issuer_Counterparty_Type,
  Issuer_Counterparty_Country,
  Issuer_Counterparty_LegalName,
  Issuer_CounterParty_Affiliate,
  Issuer_Counterparty_Affiliate_Other,
  Investment_Quality,
  Delta,
  Vega,
  DV01,
  IR_Sensitivity_Measure,
  IR_Sensitivity_Measure_Value,
  Strategy,
  Strategy_Name_Other,
  High_Freq_Trading_Indicator,
  Liquidation_Horizon_Days,
  Cleared_by_a_CCP,
  AssetClass_Other,
  Value,
  Exclude_Issuer_Counterparty,
  Exclude_Strategy,
  Exclude_Issuer_Counterparty_Country,
  Symbol,
  Instrument_Description,
  Region,
  Any_Securities_Borrowing_Lending,
  _Highlight
FROM (SELECT
  CAST(b.ID AS bigint) AS ID,
  PFA_Unique_Identifier,
  Fund_Unique_Identifier,
  Business_Date,
  Information_Date,
  Position_Unique_Identifier,
  Instrument_Group,
  Instrument_Category,
  Instrument_Type,
  Option_Instrument,
  Price,
  Local_Price,
  Quantity,
  LongShort,
  Market_Value,
  Notional_Value,
  Issuer_Counterparty,
  Issuer_Counterparty_Type,
  Issuer_Counterparty_Country,
  Issuer_Counterparty_LegalName,
  Issuer_CounterParty_Affiliate,
  Issuer_Counterparty_Affiliate_Other,
  Investment_Quality,
  Delta,
  Vega,
  DV01,
  IR_Sensitivity_Measure,
  IR_Sensitivity_Measure_Value,
  Strategy,
  Strategy_Name_Other,
  High_Freq_Trading_Indicator,
  Liquidation_Horizon_Days,
  Cleared_by_a_CCP,
  AssetClass_Other,
  Value,
  Exclude_Issuer_Counterparty,
  Exclude_Strategy,
  Exclude_Issuer_Counterparty_Country,
  Symbol,
  Instrument_Description,
  CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(Region, '@') = '@' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 PF_Region
      FROM Parameters.dbo.Country_Region_Mapping
      WHERE UPPER(Issuer_Counterparty_Country) = Country_Code)
    ELSE Region
  END AS Region,
  Any_Securities_Borrowing_Lending,
  CASE
    WHEN h.id IS NULL THEN 'N'
    ELSE 'Y'
  END AS _Highlight,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rownumber) AS rn
FROM #TepmBaseExtend b
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID
  FROM #TepmBaseExtend
  WHERE (UPPER(Exclude_Issuer_Counterparty_Country) IN ('NO','N')
         OR Exclude_Issuer_Counterparty_Country IS NULL)
    AND Business_Date = '6/30/2017'
    AND Fund_Unique_Identifier IN
        (SELECT Fund_Unique_Identifier
         FROM PFInputDemoV3..Fund_AUM_Data
         WHERE PFA_Unique_Identifier = 'TEST_DRILLDOWN_ADVISER'
           AND Business_Date = '6/30/2017'
           AND UPPER(Fund_Type) = 'HEDGE')
           AND Fund_Unique_Identifier IN
               (SELECT Fund_Unique_Identifier
                FROM PFInputDemoV3..Fund_Level_Information
                WHERE PFA_Unique_Identifier = 'TEST_DRILLDOWN_ADVISER'
                  AND Business_Date = '6/30/2017')
                  AND Market_Value > 0
                  AND UPPER(Issuer_Counterparty_Country) IN
                      (SELECT DISTINCT Country_Code
                       FROM Parameters.dbo.Country_Region_Mapping
                       WHERE UPPER(PF_Region) = UPPER('Europe_EEA'))) h
  ON h.id = b.id) tmp
WHERE rn BETWEEN 0 AND 100;

DROP TABLE #TepmBase;
DROP TABLE #TepmBaseExtend;
DROP TABLE #TempBaseDeleted;
```

Comment: This isn't MySQL, it doesn't have `ROW_NUMBER()`. I guess it's SQL-Server?

Comment: That's correct. MS SQL-Server.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not an optimization service.

Comment: The above said, If you'd like to hire me to optimize your code we can talk

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a query. These are four queries.

The date comparisons look dangerous. They only work with certain language settings. The code generating the queries should be fixed.

As to the second query: whether the index `IX_TepmBase_Audit_Date` will be used, depends on whether the DBMS regards the date criteria limiting enough. I suppose that *most* records match the condition, so let's hope the DBMS doesn't use the index. Maybe an index on `Action` would help, as we are looking for all actions starting with a particular string.

In your third query you partition by `t.id`. Shouldn't the `id` be the table's unique column; the primary key maybe? A partition doesn't seem to make sense, and `Rank` would always be 1. Then the query contains a non-correlated `NOT EXISTS` clause. Either the condition is true or false for all records. That is very likely a mistake.

For the fourth query to run fast, you'd want an index on `#TepmBaseExtend(id)`. And a further index for the derived table. Maybe on `#TepmBaseExtend(Business_Date, Market_Value, Fund_Unique_Identifier)`. Not knowing your data, I am not sure which index exactly, but that one may work.

Comment: Thank you, Kettner. I applied those indexing in 2nd and 4th query. It improved performance by 6 seconds. total time is still 5:13 minutes.

Comment: Is there any way to minimize the execution time more ?

Comment: So the indexes didn't help at all. Anyway, as mentioned I doubt that your third query is correct. Your main issue may not be time, but to get that query straight.

Comment: I rechecked it and looks like query is alright and retrieves correct information that it suppose to be.

Comment: Hm, sorry, then I'm out of clues. Which of the queries is the slow one by the way?